# Synchronize Devexpress AspxGridView with other control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I use AsxpGridView in webform.
I want to synchronize Aspxgridview with AspxFormLayout to show an employee photo like this:

[image]

(Sample taken from https://demos.devexpress.com/rwa/devav/Employees.aspx)

I don't know how to use the FocusedRowChanged Event.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have a AspxGridView in web form (Binded with Sql server datasource) table employe

Comment: I have a AspxGridView in web form (Binded with Sql server datasource) table employe.when I select a row in AspxGridView I want show his picture in other control for exeample in AspxImage.  protected void ASPxGridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            

        }

Comment: I have inserted a scerenshot for you, but you should really write better question. That English is not native language is e.g. no excuse for a bad question layout. Also, you are pointing to a DevExpress demo - don't you have that demo on your disk (or maybe you can download it from DevEx) so that you can look how it's done?